# Correct Application Structure to Safely Verify Cognito JWT Tokens

Tags: security, jwt, amazon-cognito, jwk

I'm building a React application that uses API Gateway and Lambda on the back-end. I'm going through the process of integrating Cognito authentication. I've completed the following:

```
Generate user pool

Upon login redirect to my React application with Auth Code

Extract Auth Code and send it to Token Enpoint

Receive back the id, access and refresh JWT tokens
```

I covered all that in detail in a post here: [AWS Cognito Notes](https://ncoughlin.com/posts/aws-cognito-notes/)

What I'm confused about is the concept of verifying the signature of the JWT tokens. The AWS Docs describe how to do that here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html

In short I have to download the JSON Web Key and then match it to the key on the tokens. It's not clear to me how this makes the process any safer. That key is publicly available. If I was conducting a man in the middle attack I could simply get that key and then attach it to my phony JWT token.

Which makes me think that I have a fundamental misunderstanding of this process. Should the Auth Code and JWT tokens not be sent to the React app in the first place?

Should I be setting the User Pool redirect URL to API Gateway, and have that trigger a Lambda function (that contains the client secret), to retrieve the JWT Tokens and THEN send the JWT Tokens to the React app? But then I would have the same problem of not knowing if the Tokens were legit I think? The tokens much be verified AT THE CLIENT, right?

If anyone has any insight on this or could point me to a good article I would much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was that the JWK can be stored in any capacity with the client. The JWK is publicly available, however the public key cannot be used to fake the signature itself, because the signature can only be generated with the PRIVATE key.

I did a full write up on this topic here:
https://ncoughlin.com/posts/verify-decode-cognito-jwt-tokens/

Answer (score 1):

You can use an API Gateway Authorizer to do this for you. It will check the header for ID Token and check if it is valid for your userpool. Expired and invalid tokens are rejected.

You can read more about this here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html